# Merge Replication for Huge Tables

Tags: sql, merge, replication

I have a problem. I have an audit table which is about 66 million rows, and the client wants to  replicate it to another server, but this table has no cluster index, so the only way to do it is through merge replication, but it always times out, I gues this happends because the table is tat big.

I want to know if there is a way to do this without getting the timeout error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the replication using the .NET Framework's Replication Management Objects, opening additional threads to merge the rows in chunks, and passing back responses to the application/client.

[Replication Management Object Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146869.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are other problem with your configuration. Are you certain which you configured it truly?